# Bitmap Compression Error thowing in android 13 oneplus and oppo 5g devices in android

Tags: android, kotlin, bitmap, bitmapfactory, oneplusone

when compressing image in working in oneplus and oppo android 13 5g Phone thowing error
[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUP5Q.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkbS7.png)

```
code :
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
fun bitmapToBase64(bitmap: Bitmap): String {
    val byteArrayOutputStream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream)
    val byteArray: ByteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()
    return String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(byteArray))
}

it working fine in all devices but it is throwing error only in oneplus devices and oppo,realme
how to fix. most affected device is RMX3741.
```

Comment: Check for null before use.

Comment: Bitmap:compress() will not compress to bas64.

Comment: Please do not post stacktraces in screenshots. This is pure text, please include it as text into your question and format it as code.

Comment: I have added the code. it throws errors only compressing. it is working in all devices except Oppo,relame devices